# How to extend root partition on LVM in VirtualBox with snapshots

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, fedora, lvm

I'm running Fedora 28 in VirtualBox with a 200GB virtual drive.
After a few months I ran out of disk space on the root partition.

Here's what I tried to extend it:

```
"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd "Fedora 64.vdi" --resize 300000
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

OK, so far so good. I booted the image, ran GParted, but to my surprise, the drive still showed the same size as before.

Then I tried (I know that at this point it was a stupid move), to run a [live GParted distro](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/livecd.php) and mount the whole VDI as its hdd.

I booted the live GParted and really saw the extra unused space on the drive - yay! I proceeded to extend the partition to use the extra space and booted Fedora again and...nothing. The drive seemed to have the exact same size as before. Damn!

What must I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling I stumbled upon the topic of VirtualBox **snapshots**.
I made a snapshot of my image shortly after installing some basic stuff...just in case. So what?

Commenters called it "tricky"....tldr...I decided I can live without snapshots and decided to remove mine. I tried, but got an error. Apparently more than one drive is attached to my snapshot...what?

Apparently my experiment with the live GParted created another snapshot and that's what I was extending, but that's not what my Fedora was using...what? ...why? ...sigh :-(

OK so I detached that one and removed it.

Once again I tried to remove that pesky snapshot, but that froze the whole VirtualBox application at about 67%. Killed the app, restarted, no harm done...phew...

Finally I tried again and this time was successfull. Here's what I did:

**1) resize the VDI (snapshot)**

```
"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd Snapshots\{4a09b406-a87d-4044-9d3b-51f9e7b6067e}.vdi --resize 300000
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

**2) boot Fedora and extend the partition to fill up all space using GParted**

**3) resize your LVM partition to fill up all available space (find out the path e.g. using lvdisplay)**

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/path/to/your/logical/volume
```

**4) resize the filesystem to fit the resized logical volume**

```
resize2fs /dev/path/to/your/logical/volume
```

That should do it.

Comment: While proper steps, just a few terminologies edits for you. Step 1 above was resizing the vdi partition (seen and used as a snapshot by Vbox), Step 2, was actually Step 3, resizing the File System not the partition.  This can be confusing to some but have a read here: `https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm` and skip down to figure 1 and read from there.` https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm` a partition is akin to a rented room in a house (which is the filesystem).